# How to add animated icon to OS X status bar?

Tags: cocoa, macos, statusbar

I want to put an icon in Mac OS status bar as part of my cocoa application. What I do right now is:

```
NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];

sbItem = [bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[sbItem retain];

[sbItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Taski_bar_icon.png"]];
[sbItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[sbItem setAction:@selector(stopStart)];
```

but if I want the icon to be animated (3-4 frames), how do I do it?

Comment: Well, I want to give impression that the app is processing data - happens rarely but could be good to know. Or shouldn't I?

Comment: That's a valid use. Heck, Time Machine does it.

Comment: I think Dropbox handles this quite well.  It's subtle but it tells you that things are updating.

Comment: Time Machine _used_ to do it. It doesn't happen in macOS 10.15.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll need to repeatedly call `-setImage:` on your `NSStatusItem`, passing in a different image each time. The easiest way to do this would be with an `NSTimer` and an instance variable to store the current frame of the animation.

Something like this:

```
/*

assume these instance variables are defined:

NSInteger currentFrame;
NSTimer* animTimer;

*/

- (void)startAnimating
{
    currentFrame = 0;
    animTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateImage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopAnimating
{
    [animTimer invalidate];
}

- (void)updateImage:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    //get the image for the current frame
    NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",currentFrame]];
    [statusBarItem setImage:image];
    currentFrame++;
    if (currentFrame % 4 == 0) {
        currentFrame = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to put a NSView or NSImageView on a status bar item? How to do it?

Comment: do you have to tell the animTimer to fire via [animTimer fire] or is it automatic?

Comment: The `+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` methods will add the timer to the run loop for you (that's the `scheduled` bit) so you don't need to fire the timer yourself.

Comment: - (void)updateImage:(NSTimer*)timer  add currentFrame++;

Comment: Thanks, I've added counter incrementing.

Answer (score 5):

I re-wrote Rob's solution so that I can reuse it:

I have number of frames 9 and all the images name has last digit as frame number so that I can reset the image each time to animate the icon.

```
//IntervalAnimator.h

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol IntervalAnimatorDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)onUpdate;

@end


@interface IntervalAnimator : NSObject
{
    NSInteger numberOfFrames;
    NSInteger currentFrame;
    __unsafe_unretained id <IntervalAnimatorDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(assign) id <IntervalAnimatorDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfFrames;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentFrame;

- (void)startAnimating;
- (void)stopAnimating;
@end

#import "IntervalAnimator.h"

@interface IntervalAnimator()
{
    NSTimer* animTimer;
}

@end

@implementation IntervalAnimator
@synthesize numberOfFrames;
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize currentFrame;

- (void)startAnimating
{
    currentFrame = -1;
    animTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.50 target:delegate selector:@selector(onUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopAnimating
{
    [animTimer invalidate];
}

@end
```

**How to use:**

1. Conform to protocol in your StatusMenu class

   ```
   //create IntervalAnimator object

   animator = [[IntervalAnimator alloc] init];

   [animator setDelegate:self];

   [animator setNumberOfFrames:9];

   [animator startAnimating];
   ```
2. Implement protocol method

   ```
   -(void)onUpdate    {

       [animator setCurrentFrame:([animator currentFrame] + 1)%[animator numberOfFrames]];

       NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%ld", (long)[animator currentFrame]]];

       [statusItem setImage:image];

   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Just had to do something similar recently in a simple project, so I'm posting my personal version written in Swift:

```
class StatusBarIconAnimationUtils: NSObject {
    private var currentFrame = 0
    private var animTimer : Timer
    private var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!
    private var imageNamePattern: String!
    private var imageCount : Int!

    init(statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!, imageNamePattern: String, imageCount: Int) {
        self.animTimer = Timer.init()
        self.statusBarItem = statusBarItem
        self.imageNamePattern = imageNamePattern
        self.imageCount = imageCount
        super.init()
    }

    func startAnimating() {
        stopAnimating()
        currentFrame = 0
        animTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0 / 30.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateImage(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopAnimating() {
        animTimer.invalidate()
        setImage(frameCount: 0)
    }

    @objc private func updateImage(_ timer: Timer?) {
        setImage(frameCount: currentFrame)
        currentFrame += 1
        if currentFrame % imageCount == 0 {
            currentFrame = 0
        }
    }

    private func setImage(frameCount: Int) {
        let imagePath = "\(imageNamePattern!)\(frameCount)"
        print("Switching image to: \(imagePath)")
        let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(imagePath))
        image?.isTemplate = true // best for dark mode
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.statusBarItem.button?.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private let statusItem = 
    NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

// Assuming we have a set of images with names: statusAnimatedIcon0, ..., statusAnimatedIcon6
private lazy var iconAnimation = 
    StatusBarIconAnimationUtils.init(statusBarItem: statusItem, imageNamePattern: "statusAnimatedIcon", 
    imageCount: 7)

private func startAnimation() {
    iconAnimation.startAnimating()
}

private func stopAnimating() {
    iconAnimation.stopAnimating()
}
```