# NSStatusItem title not updating when highlighted

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I made a small app which shows the CPU temperature in the status bar/Menu bar. It is working fine except it stops updating completely when it is highlighted(when i click on it). And works again when i click elsewhere(highlight is removed.). Is there a way to ensure that the app continues to update when the it is clicked on (highlighted mode).

I am using an `NSTimer` to get the temperature every 5 seconds. Even if i remove the setHighlight method, the app stops updating if i click on the statusbar app.

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSInvocation for this.

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(reload_Live_Data)]];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(reload_Live_Data)];

timer=[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 invocation: invocation repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

-(void) reload_Live_Data
{
    [_statusItem setTitle:@“xyz”];
    [_statusItem setIcon:image];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution mention in the thread [How to add animated icon to OS X status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611912/how-to-add-animated-icon-to-os-x-status-bar/29970880#29970880)

however instead of using NSTimer, you can use GCD. You can update image or title whatever you want to do.

Comment: It's not clear how the code you posted in the thread you refer to fixes the OP's problem with highlighting the status item pausing execution. Can you clarify please?